# Can sometimes be used with a continuous tense?

Tags: continuous

Can "sometimes" be used with progressive

Sometimes I drink beer

Sometimes I am driving very fast

With a continuous tense does it mean that the event happens less often than with a simple tense

Comment: Sometimes **when** I am driving fast, .....

Comment: You'd need a somewhat contrived context to make the continuous verb form acceptable in your example: *I have this dream every night where I'm driving to work in my car, but I know I'm going to be late. **Sometimes I'm driving very fast,** but usually I'm just stuck in slow-moving traffic.* For most "normal"  contexts, using the continuous verb only occurs in "Indian English", and would usually be considered "invalid" to mainstream native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm an Indian and I don't use that way.

Comment: @Raj 33: Good for you! But are you implying that you never hear *other people* using continuous verb forms like that? Here in the UK, it's a very strong indicator that the speaker isn't a native Anglophone and/or that he's much more likely to come from India than anywhere else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure about that.

Comment: It is kind of a fun challenge as well, because sometimes you're trying to win over crowds that don't want to be won over, which makes me dig a bit deeper.   it is an american who said that and he used continuous why

Comment: @Raj 33: I'm not sure what you're not sure about. Do the results from a Google search for ["indian english" "present continuous" "stative verbs"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=DkpaWqWIN87SkgXJiJigAg&q=%22indian+english%22+%22present+continuous%22+%22stative+verbs%22&oq=%22indian+english%22+%22present+continuous%22+%22stative+verbs%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.2673.2673.0.5050.3.2.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.2.0.crnk_dmh...0...1.2.64.psy-ab..1.2.165.6...73._Rt3o0DdR2k) not ring a bell with you? Me, I am knowing this for many decades.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers. You are right about that. I'm a young English learner and reading multiple globally accepted sources to improve my English. So, may be I've ignored that kind of mistakes.

Comment: @Raj 33: I don't know enough about IE to have an opinion on how acceptable the usage is *in India*, but the British 70s "sitcom" [It Ain't Half Hot Mum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081878/) often used to poke fun at it (back in the days when it was acceptable to laugh at how foreigners spoke). It may be that it's so common around you that you've never actually noticed that mainstream speakers in "fully Anglophone" countries avoid it.

Comment: ...having said that, I think sometimes IE is great! In my days as a software technician I was always glad that IE introduced us to ***prepone*** as the opposite of ***postpone***, and as a Brit I'm thoroughly signed up to [the slang usage ***Innit***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/innit), which I'm pretty sure was popularised here by people who originally came from India.

Comment: I dunno, I thought innit was completely British. Sometimes, when I'm driving fast, I fancy myself a race car driver. That's contrived? I don't think so. He did leave the rest of the sentence blank. But it is true that in IE, the simple present is often eschewed to the benefit of the continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, never, always are generally used with the simple present for general statements: I sometimes drink beer, I never drink beer, I always drink beer instead of wine.

These adverbs go with the simple present or another tense expressing generalities. For example:

**I'm always drinking beer at 6:00 pm on Friday afternoons**. It is still a ***general statement*** even if you do use the progressive.

OR
"He's always losing his temper with me."

**But the adverb must be matched to a verb**.

OR "He was sometimes playing on Saturdays instead of Sundays."

Therefore, "Sometimes, I am driving fast" on its own is not right: "I sometimes drive fast." or "Sometimes, I drive fast".

"Sometimes, when I'm driving fast, I forget everything else". In this example, the **sometimes modifies the verb forget**. So, it is grammatical.